# jqueryui modal dialog effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-effects

How can i apply effects to the modal window which contain login form. I want to apply shake effect for the dialog when use submitted the wrong details. This code is failed

```
$("#dialog-form").effect("shake", { times:5 }, 100);
```

This is applying the effect to only form not for modal dialog. Is there any way to apply the effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply the effect to the dialog widget itself. You can write:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog("widget").effect("shake", { times: 5 }, 100);
```

In passing, note that shaking the dialog box in response to invalid input might not be understood by some of your users. I'd suggest you use a clear, understandable validation message instead.

Comment: Cancel: function() {                                                                             
               $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("widget").effect("explode", {}, 100,function(){
             $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "close" );
                   }}   is giving error in IE6 and IE closing automatically after showing Send/Don't send message.

Comment: It crashes the browser? It might be worth a bug report to Microsoft, although I'm not sure it will be acted upon. After all, Internet Explorer 6 was released in 2001, and even Google does not support it nowadays...